# Как работает алгоритм Диффи — Хеллмана для чата

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, python-3.x, алгоритм

Я хочу сделать безопасную передачу сообщений в закрытой чат-комнате. В руме может быть до 10 человек. Я не могу понять, как мне сделать безопасную передачу ключа другим пользователям?

Увидел алгоритм передачи ключа Диффи — Хеллмана, по сути:

- пользователь передает зашифрованное сообщения вместе с куском ключом шифрования, на сервер;
- с сервера сообщения и ключ по вебсокетам переходит другим пользователям;
- на фронте они получают это сообщение и расшифровывают его с помощью ключа.

Но как сделать эту передачу другим пользователям я не могу понять. Сам сервер видит только зашифрованное сообщения и он его просто передает другим.

Если можно напишите псевдокод или пример, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Безопасная передача невозможна, если собеседники не встретились лично и не обменялись ключами самостоятельно

Comment: тогда зачем придумали алгоритм обмена ключами ?

Comment: @andreymal тогда зачем алгоритм? и как тогда хранить этот ключ? Как пароль от аккаунта? он все равно же будет показываться на фронт и бэк